# How to diagnose airflow deadlocks?

Tags: airflow

My airflow pipeline has fallen into a deadlocked state for several different reasons, and each time it is a guessing game to figure out the issue. I would like to create a checklist for when a pipeline appears to be deadlocked.

What are the most common causes of deadlock when using airflow, and what steps should be taken to verify and remediate each type of deadlock?